# Checking foreach loop list results C#

Tags: c#, list, foreach

I have this bit of code in a class:

```
public class TicketSummary
    {

        //get all the development tickets
        public List<IncidentSummary> AllDevelopmentTickets { get; set; }
      public List<string> TicketNames()
        {
            List<string> v = new List<string>();

            foreach (var developmentTicket in AllDevelopmentTickets)
            {
                var ticketIds = developmentTicket.id.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                v.Add(ticketIds);
            }

            return v;
        }  
    }
}
```

And I am trying to see if my API connection (plus all the code) did it's job and pulls back the tickets and their info, more specifically the ids.

In my main program I have no clue how to check if it did the job. I tried something but it isn't quite right and doesn't return anything ( I know I need a Console.WriteLine)

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.ReadLine();


            var tickets = new TicketSummary();
            tickets.TicketNames();
            while ( tickets != null )
            {
                Console.WriteLine(tickets);
            }

        }
```

Any suggestions, please?

Thank you!

Comment: Just a suggestion: don't use `var` as a variable name as it's a keyword in C#. It's confusing.

Comment: It returns but you are ignoring the return value

Comment: `tickets.TicketNames();` looks like it should return something? `while ( tickets != null )` is a loop that never ends - you don't alter it inside the loop.

Comment: @StuartLC `var` isn't actually reserved, the above code is valid. Nevertheless, it's bad practice to use `var` as the name of a variable, as it's also a keyword in C#.

Comment: `var` is not a reserved word in C#. It is a contextual keyword, you could use it as a variable name(without any problem), but doing so is discouraged.

Comment: I understand, thanks for the info :) it is a test console but I do want to learn how to program correctly, hence why i edited my code real quick. Regarding the code, yes i know it was a forever loop but I had no clue how to fix it! And yes it should show something but it never did!

Comment: @aevitas + sriram - thanks fellas - I learned something today.

Comment: Guys, [could we please be a little nicer to new users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users) There's no reason to downvote a question just because the code in the question is of poor quality - I bet you have, at least once, written code that's worse than anything in this question, even if it was pretty long ago. You have to start out somewhere!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign / use the return value of the `TicketNames()` method. This seems a lot of work just to return the string version of the TicketId. This can be reduced

```
public List<string> TicketNames()
{
    return AllDevelopmentTickets
        .Select(t => t.id.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        .ToList();
}  

   var ticketSummary = new TicketSummary();
   var ticketNames = ticketSummary.TicketNames();

    foreach(var ticketName in ticketNames)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ticketName);
    }
```

or Even just:

```
  foreach(var ticketName in AllDevelopmentTickets
        .Select(t => t.id.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)))
  {
      Console.WriteLine(ticketName);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You've dropped the returned result: `tickets.TicketNames();` returns `List<String>` that you *have to assign* and then *itterate*:

```
 var tickets = new TicketSummary();
 var names = tickets.TicketNames(); // <- names, List<String> according to the code

 // printing out all the names
 foreach(var name in names)   
   Console.WriteLine(name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you just want to print all the tickets out?

```
foreach (var ticket in tickets.TicketNames())
{
    Console.WriteLine(ticket);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems in your code, that should keep it from even compiling, but aside from that, It seem's what you're really after is rather *transforming* the data in `AllDevelopmentTickets`, rather than *moving* it somewhere. So you could probably do it with a `Select` call (from LINQ). So, in your main method:

```
var tickets = new TicketSummary();
// add some tickets to tickets.AllDevelopmentTickets here...

var ticketNames = tickets.AllDevelopmentTickets.Select(ticket => ticket.id.ToString();
// Yes, you should probably use an UI culture in the ToString call. 
// I'm just trying to limit my line width =)
```

Now, `ticketNames` should be an `IEnumerable<string>` holding all the ticket ids. To, for example, print them out, you can iterate over them and write to console output:

```
foreach (var name in ticketNames) {
    Console.WriteLine(name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're ignoring the returned value.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.ReadLine();


        var tickets = new TicketSummary();
        var res = tickets.TicketNames();
        while ( for r in res )
        {
            Console.WriteLine(r);
        }

    }
```